# how to retrieve specific card without using card id? stripe, django

Tags: python, django, credit-card

I know we can use stripe customer id to retrieve list of cards attached to the customer id.  Also, I know we can retrieve ONE specific card with the card's id....But what if I do not want to use the card id to retrieve the card.  Instead I want to use exp month, year, last4.  Is this possible?

I thought of

```
        all_cards = stripe.Customer.retrieve(cus_id).sources.all(object=CARD)
        the_card = all_cards.all(
            exp_month=data.get(EXP_MONTH),
            exp_year=data.get(EXP_YEAR),
            last4=data.get(LAST_4)
        )
```

but it says no such parameters such as `exp_month`

I thought of doing it in a way to loop through all the card and match the parameters which myself believes would be a bad idea if there is a better one.

Does anyone have a better idea or suggestions?

Thanks in advance for any advise

Comment: Perhaps you can describe your problem abstractly so that one can reason about it without having to understand the context.

Answer (score 0):

According to stripe documentation: no. https://stripe.com/docs/api/python#retrieve_card

There is a simple reason for that: the data might not be unique. Your customer, by some weird luck might have two or more cards ending the same month and year(well, actually that's not that weird) and with the same last 4 digits.

If you are working with some legacy system and need to retrieve some old data about the cards from Stripe, I'd create a management command to just fill the blanks: get the data from Stripe and attach card_id to the objects you already have.

Ps. you might be interested in this library: https://github.com/ArabellaTech/aa-stripe/ - disclaimer: I am one of the authors.